# Is it possible to start Fragment class from an Activity class..Using Intent

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have a MainActivity class,Is it possible to start a fragment class using Button onclicklistner

Main Activity Class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button r_btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_register);
    r_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, test.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

Fragment Class

```
public class test extends Fragment{

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test, container, false);
    rootView.findViewById(R.id.label1);

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return rootView;
    }
}
```

Any tips would be helpful..

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can but you cant treat fragment like activity so you cant use `startActivity` method. Use fragment manager to call fragment

```
 fragmentContainer = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.fragmentContainer);

  r_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           replaceFragmentInContainer(new test(), fragmentContainer.getId(), getSupportFragmentManager());
        }
    });



 public void replaceFragmentInContainer(Fragment DestinationFragment,int containerResourceID,FragmentManager fragmentManager )
    {
        FragmentTransaction ft=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        int viewResourceID = containerResourceID;
        ft.replace(viewResourceID, DestinationFragment);
        ft.commit();
    }
```

Your container in activity xml that will handle your fragment

```
 <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            >
        </RelativeLayout>
```

or you can check [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/117838/introduction-to-android-fragments-tutorial)

Comment: ok thank u..i will check...can i use extend fragment class like extend activity class?bcoz i have only single screen..i want to use extend fragment class instead off ectend activity..is this possible?for example login screen,registartion....

Comment: activity can have as many fragment as possible so you can create one activity and many fragment to it . as per your need.

Comment: on more doubt..i searched many examples about navigation drawer..but in all cases they are using fragments instead of activity..i meant i want to open my activity classes when i click navigation items...but in most examples item clicks going to fragments..can i use activites in navigation drawer?